# iOS vs Android Debugging

Tags: android, ios, debugging

In Android I set a break point in a function, press skip over, and then eventually I go to another function. In iOS, I set a break point in a function, press skip over, and I never get to the next function because it goes into something that looks like assembly code.

In iOS, is there a way to set a break point and go from one function to the next one that is called?

Comment: When I use "step into" it loops through the assembly code forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip over a function that has a breakpoint on it, you just need to run the code and when it stops, the debug area should have 4 options beside the view/hide debug area button visible.

It will have:

- A pause button or play button depending on the state
- An arrow going over top of a line (which is the step over option you are looking for)
- An arrow going down into a line (the step into option)
- An arrow coming out of a line (the step out option)

After choosing the step over button just click the play button on the DEBUG AREA (important) and your code will continue on it's way without the function call. Hopefully this helps you out a bit

Comment: Thank you, but I want it to stop in the next function that it hits without me having to put in a break point. If I just press play then it will continue until it hits another break point. 

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @KatrinaFish Unfortunately as far as I am aware, unless you place a breakpoint the program is just going to continue running after starting the loop again until it does hit another breakpoint, at that point you can skip over another line or what ever option you choose. I believe there are hotkeys that make doing this a little less painful but I don't remember them, I tend to ignore the breakpoints and follow problems back to the source from the output feed. Try googling for the hotkeys

Comment: So then the answer is you can't. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in "another function". This "assembly loop" is not infinite, btw. It's just iOS's internal functions.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Is there a way to have the debugger step into another function without having to set a break point?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In Xcode, these buttons help you with navigating during debugging with breakpoins. From left to right, we have

1. The pause execution button - The button will change to 'Continue Execution' button. Use this to either jump from one break point to another or to simply continue execution after a pause.
2. Step over - To step over an instruction
3. Step into - To step into an instruction
4. Step out - To step out of an instruction

You can always use Step out or Step over or Continue execution button to get out of assembly code loop.